# Strip path segment while extracting using 7zip? 

Tags: path, 7-zip, extract

Is there a way to extract a 7z archive that contains all it's files within a directory without creating this directory in the file system but still keeping the sub-directory structure of the archive (so `7z e ...` is not working as desired, because it strips all path info)?

In tar I would use `tar -x --strip=1 ...` to strip the first path component. Is there some equivalent for 7z or do I have to extract with the unwanted path segment, move the contents to the right place and delete the directory?

Comment: Looking at 7z command line options, I don't it's possible in one shot. Probably use `7z x` to create the structure, `7z e` to strip path info and then delete the files created by `7z x`, tried it, it's still not what you want.

Comment: Although you can't do this while *extracting*, you can strip the archive root folder when *compressing*. Instead of `7z a archive.7z path\to\folder` do `7z a archive.7z path\to\folder\*` to strip `folder` from the archived path name.

Comment: @jpaugh I'm not the one who packs the file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the GUI.

1. Navigate within the archive to the directory you want.
2. Select either that directory or its contents.
3. Either

   - drag-and-drop it (or its contents) to a folder in your file manager; or
   - use the 7-Zip GUI's Extract button.

(Apologies in advance if a graphical solution is no good; I wasn't sure from my reading of your question.)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the command-line:

```
7z x archive.7z
cd <directory name>
mv * ..
rmdir <directory name>
```

yes, this sounds like your "do I have to extract with the unwanted path segment, move the contents to the right place and delete the directory?"

Comment: Major pain if your don't know the directory name because datetime is part of it. And no I did not create the file.

Comment: @Martin In that case, you could modify the command slightly to account for any single folder at the top level. `mkdir /tmp/known-folder& cd /tmp/known-folder; 7z x /path/to/archive.7z; cd *; mv * /where/you/want/the/files; cd $HOME; rm -rf /tmp/known-folder`